# Property of the Gamma function

Tags: gamma-function

I want to know is there any property due to which we could write $$\frac{\Gamma(M+\frac{2}{\alpha})}{\Gamma(M)}=\frac{2}{\alpha}\sum_{k=1}^{M} \frac{\Gamma(k-1+\frac{2}{\alpha})}{(k-1)!}$$ Thanks in advance.

Comment: The tag [tag:proof-verification] should only be used when you're actually verifying a proof is correct - but you haven't included any work or proof here. Also, please use a *good* title that describes your problem. The title you have communicates absolutely nothing about your question.

Comment: @T.Bongers I have changed the title of the question.

Comment: Actually I am trying to get the eq(43) of http://arxiv.org/abs/1405.2013 (where the value of $k_1$ is provided in eq(18) of the paper) this equation becomes valid only when the above property is true. Note that I changed the upper limit from $\infty$ to $M$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use $\Gamma(x+1) = x \cdot \Gamma(x)$ and induction.
If $M=1$ then 
$$\frac{\Gamma(1+\frac{2}{\alpha})}{\Gamma(1)}=\Gamma\left(1+\frac{2}{\alpha}\right)
=\frac{2}{\alpha}\Gamma\left(\frac{2}{\alpha}\right)=\frac{2}{\alpha}\sum_{k=1}^{1} \frac{\Gamma(k-1+\frac{2}{\alpha})}{(k-1)!}.$$

If $M>1$ then 
$$\frac{2}{\alpha}\sum_{k=1}^{M} \frac{\Gamma(k-1+\frac{2}{\alpha})}{(k-1)!}=
\frac{2}{\alpha}\sum_{k=1}^{M-1} \frac{\Gamma(k-1+\frac{2}{\alpha})}{(k-1)!}+
\frac{2}{\alpha}\frac{\Gamma(M-1+\frac{2}{\alpha})}{(M-1)!}\\=
\frac{\Gamma(M-1+\frac{2}{\alpha})}{\Gamma(M-1)}+\frac{2}{\alpha}\frac{\Gamma(M-1+\frac{2}{\alpha})}{(M-1)!}=\left(M-1+\frac{2}{\alpha}\right)\frac{\Gamma(M-1+\frac{2}{\alpha})}{(M-1)!}=\frac{\Gamma(M+\frac{2}{\alpha})}{\Gamma(M)},$$
where we used the induction step and the fact that $\Gamma(n) = (n-1)!$ for any positive integer $n$.

Comment: Your answer is right but is there any other way that we can find that the property is correct. I am a bit skeptic about induction. Nevertheless, it was excellent help and thanks alot.